# Windows - PHP SSH Remote Connection

Tags: php, windows, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Execute SSH Commands Via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270419/how-to-execute-ssh-commands-via-php)

I've searched here for some solutions but I couldn't find anything useful, so I'll just ask it.

OK, so what I want to do is a SSH Remote Connection FROM my website to the remote server machine. Both are Windows for now but I'll get some Linux servers soon so I will have to make it compatible with Linux systems. Well, back to topic. I'm currently trying to create a Game Server Control Panel in PHP which will start and stop .exe's over the internet on my Dedicated Servers, but I need to know how to do it in PHP.

I've currently not come up with anything at all because this is still an idea of mine.
I know I should make it in ASP.NET but I have no knowledge in ASP.NET whatsoever.

I've installed Cygwin Server on my remote machine and it's working.

How do I make a PHP SSH Connection to my remote machine(s)?

EDIT: I have full root access to both machines.

Comment: PHP vs ASP make up your mind ;)

Comment: Why not just create a web service?  seems to be a better option

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php

Comment: Getting libssh2 working on a Windows box is a PITA. Try phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation, instead: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use PHP's `exec()` function to execute a script to do what you need.  See here:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Eugh. Dropping down the shell should be the last resort. There is at least one perfectly good SSH library available for PHP.