# Shell commands in pure PHP implementation

Tags: php, shell-exec

Is there any kind of PHP's pure implementation of shell commands ?
I mean some kind of interface to executing "shell" commands, that instead
using exec/shell_exec/system, executes their native php implementations.

For example:
"ls -l" executes php implementation based on opendir/scandir/readdir/closedir functions.
"mkdir example" executes something like: mkdir('example') etc.

Regards

Comment: I'm having a hard time imagining why anybody would ever need this. What is your use case?

Comment: @Pekka웃: +1. Also, I find this highly insecure.

Comment: @OptimusCrime: More insecure than executing shell commands directly?

Comment: I don't think such a library exists in one pack. Executing shell commands is one thing but the command itself can be just like anything and so you have to deal with all of them if you want to translate them  to php functions.

Comment: @Pekka웃 It happens pretty often for me to have to run shell commands in a hosting environment without ssh access.
Unfortunately hostings i use, doesn't allow using exec/passthru/system/shell_exec commands.

FTP is not an option when i need to delete/move/copy more than 100 000 files, because it tooks ages to complete.
Finding and deleting files within specific path using regex is not user friendly also.
Now, i do it via a simple php scripts, but sometimes i need to do it ASAP.

I just need an easy and intuitive interface to deal with this type operations.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at the [file functions of PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php).

You can list files, make directories, remove them... but of course, you won't find all you can find a a shell.

Answer (score -2):

Either use

```
shell_exec("your command here");
```

or

```
echo exec("your command here");
```

Also take a look at these sites:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
>
> [How To Execute SSH Commands Via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270419/how-to-execute-ssh-commands-via-php)
>
> [php shell_exec() vs exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec)