# Pass form variable to SSH PHP script

Tags: php, forms, variables, ssh, phpseclib

I am trying to pass a form variable to phpseclib ssh as a hostname. Something like this:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
IP OR HOSTNAME: <input type="text" name="ipaddr">

<?php
$ipaddr = $_POST["ipaddr"];
$ssh = new ssh2('$ipaddr');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
echo $ssh->exec('command1');
echo $ssh->exec('command2');
?>
```

Doesn't appear to be working. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what ssh2 library you're using, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270419/how-to-execute-ssh-commands-via-php -- otherwise, there's PHP's `ssh2_*` functions: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-auth-password.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using phpseclib you should be doing this:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($ipaddr);
```

Instead of what you are doing:

```
$ssh = new ssh2('$ipaddr');
```

Note how it's `Net_SSH2` instead of `ssh2`. Also note how `$ipaddr` isn't in single quotes. The fact that that's unnecessary not withstanding variables aren't replaced when single quotes are used.