# Remote shutdown using PHP and SSH

Tags: php, ssh, remote-access, shutdown, phpseclib

What I want is a PHP file that I can call that shuts a computer down using SSH. Simple as that. Below is something that I've knocked up. Obviously, it doesn't work. I'm no PHP expert. Maybe a PHP expert could show me how to get it working. Thanks.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('192.168.1.124');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$ssh->write("sudo shutdown -h now");
sleep(5);
$ssh->write("password\n");

?>
```

Comment: does this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270419/how-to-execute-ssh-commands-via-php ?

Comment: I tried that but it comes up with host key validation errors and other crazy errors. Give me a minute and I'll tell you the exact errors and the code I've used.

Comment: I've put echo in front of the $ssh->writes in my code above, it echo's 11 in the browser. I've also tried echo '$ssh->exec('sudo shutdown -h now');' but it shows 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified' in the browser. 'echo $ssh->exec('ssh -t -t 192.168.1.124 "sudo shutdown -h now"');' tells me that 'Host key verification failed.' Thanks

Comment: then I think its some sort of SSH error and nothing to do with PHP as such.

Comment: How to do sudo with phpseclib: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a way to shutdown the computer safely using an AppleScript.

The PHP file is:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('192.168.1.124');
if (!$ssh->login('josephftaylor', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('osascript Documents/shutdown.scpt');

?>
```

The AppleScript is saved in my documents and is:

```
tell application "System Events"
    shut down
end tell
```

Hope this helps anyone else trying to do something similar to me. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score -1):

You could try giving 'username' NOPASSWD privileges to /sbin/shutdown

Log into the remote box and do `sudo visudo`

Add the following line (adjust for correct username):

```
username ALL= NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

Now that user should be able to `sudo shutdown` without a password, and hopefully `sudo` won't get mad about not being on a tty.

[Source](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_allow_non-super_users_to_shutdown_computer_in_Linux)

Comment: This is a very bad idea - shutdown down a production machine *should* require supercow privileges, for obvious reasons. Additionally, the "password" is a good safe-guard for doing stupid things, like **halting** a server.

Comment: I tried it and it still didn't work. I must have done it wrong.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, I would agree, but the OP must give himself the privileges to accomplish his goal. If the goal **is** to shutdown the machine, then it's **not** a security risk. As long as the user account is dedicated to only this script, and this script is properly protected then it won't be an issue.

Comment: I'm trying to shutdown my Mac using a PHP file stored on my Raspberry Pi, I want to be able to either run the PHP file direct from a browser, or to use SiriProxy to run the PHP file.

Comment: Still sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Comment: When I run 'echo $ssh->exec('sudo shutdown -h now');'

Comment: Using 'echo $ssh->exec('ssh -l josephftaylor 192.168.1.14 "sudo shutdown -h now"');' Shows 'Permission denied, please try again. Permission denied, please try again. Permission denied (publickey,password).' in the browser.

Comment: Using the exec() method will require certificate based authentication so that you don't have to enter the password to authenticate to the remote machine. `ssh-keygen` from your R-PI, then `ssh-copy-id`. This will generate a cert, and install it onto your MAC so that the actual `exec()` call to the `ssh` command won't require a password. The the sudo changes you made earlier should allow the shutdown command to execute as your user.

Comment: Okay, I ran 'ssh-keygen' on the Pi then 'ssh-copy-id -i rsa.pub_location josephftaylor@192.168.1.124'. Still doesn't work. I must be a major retard.