# SSH Connection and command in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, ssh, command, key

I have some project to do but killing myself and cannot do anything, i need you help .
I am have to make PHP Command to use SSH Connection. 
I am using Putty , entering IP and Port, than browsing .PPK file ( key authentication file ) and Entering Username And Password, after using command Reboot . so server is rebooting.

Now i want to make all of this simply using PHP  , i want to make a textbox and submit button , when entering IP address in textbox and clicking submit button it should make all this reboot command in background. (port is default 22). I will make this textboxes and buttons but cannot get how to make this connection with command and key authentication.
if somebody know this please help me solving this problem. i cannot take it any more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270419/how-to-execute-ssh-commands-via-php

Answer (score 1):

You must use **phpseclib**.

- Download it from [**here**](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) or  [**here**](http://break-point.ir/dl/phpseclib0.3.5.zip) ( direct link ) .
- Include it to your project.

And then :

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.example.com');
$ssh->login('username', 'password') or die("Login failed");
// $ssh->getServerPublicHostKey(); if this is your first time connecting
// check $ssh->getServerPublicHostKey() against previously saved 
//                                value on subsequent connections
echo $ssh->exec('reboot');
```

Comment: I have donwloaded PHPseclib from your link and uploaded on server . after created index.php with code :

include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('IP address', 22);
$ssh->login('myusername', 'mypass') or die("Login failed");
echo $ssh->exec('reboot');

after what to do it says login Failed . WHere i have to give Key File?

Comment: did you tried `$ssh = new Net_SSH2('IP address');` without port number ?

Comment: not yet but i cannot understand where i have to put my PPK key file for authentication, without key auth it's not logging

Comment: what do you mean `without key auth it's not logging`, I dont think its necessary here .

Comment: I mean that there is Private Key written in file. PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: aes256-cbc. Without loading this key putty is not connecting with server.this is secured connection so i need to load this key in case of logging

Comment: when you are connection to remote server in ssh, with PHP, it has nothing to do with `putty`, putty is just a software . by the way, I dont know, search about this subject, I just answered your question `ssh connection and command php`. good luck

Comment: ahha thank you for this help , i Know that putty is a soft and i want to make the same connection web-based so the one thing was to use PHP

Comment: good luck , go [**here**](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net) maybe you can find your answer .

Comment: look at the update, I found it in [**here**](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html)

Comment: You load the key by doing `$rsa = new Crypt_RSA(); $rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents('/path/to/key.ppk')); $ssh->login('username', $key);`