# Access a different hosting account using PHP

Tags: php, laravel, server, cpanel, whm

I am building a dashboard to control couple different websites (each is **in a cPanel separate account** (including the Dashboard), but all hosted on the same server).

The dashboard will use php's `shell_exec` for example to execute shell commands inside a website's directory:

```sh
shell_exec('cd /home/website/www/app/ && php artisan config:cache')
```

Or simply read a file:

```php
file_get_content('/home/website/www/app/license');
```

Of course, by default, accounts are not allowed to have access to each other like this! Is there a way to allow one account/user to access/modify other accounts?

Comment: The users need to be in the same group, and the files & directories need to be group readable (possibly group writable & executable as well, depending on what all you want to be able to do).

Comment: Or alternatively, you could define access to specific commands within your sudoers file without opening up the user permissions.  https://serverfault.com/questions/294661/how-to-grant-sudo-rights-only-to-specific-script-files

Comment: @Vince I added both the "dashboard" and the "website1" users to the "clients" group. Using `usermod -a -G clients [user]`. Now, should i make the files I want to access group-readable, or also every directory in the path? e.g /home/ & /home/website1/ & /home/website1/www/ ... etc?

Comment: If users need to read a given file `path/to/file.ext`, the directories `path`, and `to` need to be, at minimum, group readable. But other files within those directories do not necessarily need to be group readable. You also need to be sure that your web server is running as a user in the same group. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Vince I found that every directory is already group-readable/writable already. Also I added "root" to the "clients" group (after I found that apache is running as root!). But I still get permission denied.

Comment: @Vince I am actually trying to just read a file for now. And as for running apache as root, I am actually not sure, all of this is new to me! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Idk man. I did just notice you are calling `file_get_content` rather than `file_get_contents` here, but you're probably doing it right in your actual code. I'm stumped. If the file is group-readable, and the web server is in the same group as the the file, it should have permission to read it.

Comment: @Vince I feel close to the solution, but I don't know what to do. How can I know the user of the web server?

Comment: @Vince Also, should change the "group" for the directory, or the user being in the group is enough?

Comment: You can see what user Apache is running as by running `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` (see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/133932)). It ***should*** be running as `www-data`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200318/discussion-between-dewan159-and-vince).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use SSH as this would not restrict you having to be on a single server and means that you do not have to breach the isolation of each cPanel account.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php

I would suggest using this or alternatively this:

[How To Execute SSH Commands Via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270419/how-to-execute-ssh-commands-via-php)

Comment: Sounds great, but this would need me to change ALOT of the code I have written sadly. I will make it my last resort. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Supposing Apache is running as `www-data` in the group `www-data` any file you need the server to have access to should be group-readable and have the group `www-data`.

You can see what Apache is running as by running:

```
ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
```

Also remember, the whole path to the file needs to be readable by the group. In other words, given a file `/path/to/some/file.txt` the directories `path`, `to`, and `some` all need to be group readable and have the group `www-data` (or whatever Apache is running as).